# What does this warning mean?

Tags: linux, dynamic, gdb, warnings

I have often encountered the following warning from gdb:

`warning: .dynamic section for XXX is not at the
expected address`

where XXX is the name of some library.
Most recently I got it for libgobject-2.0.so. My app uses GTK. gdb had been launching it without problems till yesterday when I synced the latest code from the repository and built it afresh. Since then it has been complaining about .dynamic section. What are the possible reasons for it? And how do I resolve them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some gdb versions are actually a bit more helpful with that warning. They output something like the following:

warning: .dynamic section for "libhello.so" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

Make sure GDB finds the library your program was actually compiled with and that any debugging symbols, if in separate files, for the application and the library are current and consistent with the builds you are using.

An upgrade sounds like a good suspect for a cause. Prelinking libraries might also cause this warning to appear, although I think gdb can handle that case.

Comment: A typical case for this: T1) app was started and kept running with old binaries, T2) then the binaries/symbols were "upgraded" on the disk (but app was not restarted), T3) then the app crashed (or a gcore was generated). By looking at timestamp of upgrade (T2) and timestamp of coredump (T3) - one would assume the proper (upgraded) lib was used. Wrong assumption! Knowing this in advance would've saved my day... Our apps are using a custom LD_LIBRARY/etc startup env, so we had to exhaust all the other options before facing the obvious (IT guys just forgot to restart the apps after the upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the gdb failed to locate your shared libraries. Launch gdb and make sure to set **both** "sysroot" and "solib-search-path":

```
> gdb your_program_binary core_file
(gdb) set sysroot YOUR_SHARED_LIBRARIES_PATH
(gdb) set solib-search-path YOUR_SHARED_LIBRARIES_PATH
(gdb) bt
```

You can also add these set commands to "~/.gdbinit" and then launch gdb.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too just now and it can't be caused by what thkala mentioned... Live investigation follows.

I have a single gdb running. `ps fax | grep -B1 jackdbus` shows:

```
61747 pts/8    Sl+    0:00  |       \_ gdb
61764 pts/8    t      0:00  |           \_ /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus auto
```

Inside that gdb I had a breakpoint on `main` (so it never really ran), but I did run it (with arg `auto`) to load the shared libraries, and gdb prints:

```
warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)
```

Unless there is something extremely wrong with the build system of jack2, those two belong together (were compiled at the same time).

So what is causing this warning? My investigation:

```
# cat /proc/61764/maps | grep 'jack'
555555554000-55555555a000 r--p 00000000 00:2f 33145                      /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus
55555555a000-555555566000 r-xp 00006000 00:2f 33145                      /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus
555555566000-55555556d000 r--p 00012000 00:2f 33145                      /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus
55555556e000-555555570000 r--p 00019000 00:2f 33145                      /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus
555555570000-555555571000 rw-p 0001b000 00:2f 33145                      /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus
7ffff7efe000-7ffff7f29000 r--p 00000000 fe:03 1976021                    /usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
7ffff7f29000-7ffff7f72000 r-xp 0002b000 fe:03 1976021                    /usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
7ffff7f72000-7ffff7f99000 r--p 00074000 fe:03 1976021                    /usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
7ffff7f99000-7ffff7f9a000 ---p 0009b000 fe:03 1976021                    /usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
7ffff7f9a000-7ffff7fa0000 r--p 0009b000 fe:03 1976021                    /usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
7ffff7fa0000-7ffff7fa1000 rw-p 000a1000 fe:03 1976021                    /usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
```

Hit in one... The *actual* shared library that is loaded is `/usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0`.

gdb is simply lying about the path what was actually loaded (and its still a case of what thkala mentioned)!

Also note the output of `info shared`:

```
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7f29040  0x00007ffff7f71ed3  Yes         /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/lib/libjackserver.so.0
```

The library at that path *does* have debug info (but the missing `(*)` below `Read`) means that `Shared library is missing debugging information.` Another indication that the actual library loaded and the path shown here are not the same.

Note that I have the following gdb variables set:

```
(gdb) show sysroot
The current system root is "/nonexistent".
(gdb) show solib-search-path
The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is /usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/lib:/usr/lib.
```

(See `set solib-search-path` on the page https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-shared-libraries for the reason why).

Apparently, setting `solib-search-path` has an effect on where gdb finds the shared libraries, but NOT on which shared libraries are actually loaded.

Following [this](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/424-setting-ld-library-path-when-using-the-gnu-project-debugger-gdb-) answer I therefore added also `set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/lib` to `/usr/src/jack2/.gdbinit` (from where I am running `gdb`; note that I have in my `~/.gdbinit` the line: `add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/src/jack2` in order to actually load it). It turned out that I could also simply delete the lines that set sysroot and solib-search-path. The complete `.gdbinit` now being:

```
cd /usr/src/jack2
directory src/jack2-1.9.14/linux
set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/jack2/pkg/jack2/usr/lib
file pkg/jack2/usr/bin/jackdbus
set args auto
b main
command 1
b JackLinuxFutex.cpp:137
b JackLinuxFutex.cpp:156
end
run
```

This solved the problem.